# How do i let a user save an image from gallery to his SharedPrefferences?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

How do I let a user save an image from gallery to his SharedPreferences?

I am now using this code so the user can select an image from his preferred gallery. How do i save his picture of choice to the SharedPreferences?

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnUploadPicture)
{
    Intent uploadPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
    startActivityForResult(uploadPic, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
}
```

Comment: Since shared preference is use to save small amount of data it is not feasible to use shared preferences for storing image. I would suggest you to Save image to external storage and then save the path of image as a string in shared preferences.

Comment: can i instead save the image path? (like where it is being stored in the device)

Comment: yes i have suggested that only

Comment: how do i do such thing?

Comment: as Base64, but is so bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image path in the shared preferences and later get the image path from the shared preferences.

The image path can be obtained like this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

        File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

        System.out.println(mImageCaptureUri);
    }  
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. But it sounds looks like the real issue is that you don't know how to handle the image when you return from the startActivityForResult.
When you use startActivityForResult, onActivityResult is always ran when it returns from said activity.
You'll need to override onActivityResult in your class.

I suggesting making

```
final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
```

a global variable so you can use it in startActivityForResult. Because you need to surround your code with an if statement, so that it doesn't get ran when returning from another activity.

Place the following override method in your class.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        System.out.println("Successfully Returned from Gallery with Image")
        //This is your image from the gallery
        if (data != null) {
            Uri fileUri = data.getData();
            //This is where you will do what you need with the image. 
            //Maybe set an ImageView
            //imageView.setImageURI(fileUri);
            //Or you can copy the image to the app's gallery
            //Add URI to SharedPrefs 

        }

    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "An Error Has Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_ERROR)
what activity am i supposed to enter here? the activity which contains this code or a different one?

Comment: The onActivityResult method will be in the original activity. When startActivityForResult is called, the app will be sent to a 2nd activity with the expectation of a 'result'. When the app returns to the original activity it runs onActivityResult with following parameters:  requestCode, resultCode and data. ResultCode is either -1 or 0. This indicates if the 2nd activity ran successfully or was canceled.
else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_ERROR) allows you to handle the 2nd activity if it was canceled. In this case, a Toast message will be presented to the user, letting them know.

Comment: I understood, thanks for the help

Comment: If you found one of the answers proved, please mark it as a solution. Likewise if you found a comment helpful click the up arrow so that others may more easily location useful information in the future.